# Installing Kotlin Kernel to Jupyter Notebook

Tags: kotlin, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, kernel

I'm trying to use Kotlin Kernel on Jupyter notebook (on VScode).

I have created a virtual environment.

I have installed jupyter notebook and kotlin-jupyter-kernel via pip.

When I select kernel from jupyter notebook and run a code, it says;

```
Failed to start the Kernel. 
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] System cannot find specified path. 
View Jupyter log for further details.
```

Jupyter logs are too long and complex but I can paste if you request.

Also this is my kernel.json for kotlin kernel;

```
{
    "display_name": "Kotlin",
    "language": "kotlin",
    "interrupt_mode": "message",
    "argv": [
        "python",
        "-m",
        "run_kotlin_kernel",
        "{connection_file}"
    ],
    "metadata": {
        "jar_path_detect_command": [
            "python",
            "-m",
            "kotlin_kernel",
            "detect-jars-location"
        ]
    }
}
```

Below is detailed output from VScode when I try to run the code ( as Ilya requested)

```
02:39:50.043 [info] Handle Execution of Cells 0 for d:\02_Kotlin\notebook.ipynb
02:39:50.043 [info] Starting Kernel startUsingLocalKernelSpec, .jvsc74a57bd02cf58050246a8fb90d5b6f26f72786d7604fc9ac535b400b803d90ad93e2fe03#kotlin.d:\02_Kotlin\my_kotlin_env\Scripts\python.exe.\.python#-m#run_kotlin_kernel#{connection_file}  (Python Path: d:\02_Kotlin\my_kotlin_env\Scripts\python.exe, Venv, my_kotlin_env, 3.11.4) for 'd:\02_Kotlin\notebook.ipynb' (disableUI=false)
02:39:50.141 [info] Launching Raw Kernel Kotlin # python
02:39:50.151 [info] Process Execution: python -m run_kotlin_kernel ~\AppData\Roaming\jupyter\runtime\kernel-v2-178083DnF0uMW4VHD.json
    > cwd: d:\02_Kotlin
02:39:52.315 [warn] StdErr from Kernel Process Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 198, in _run_module_as_main
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 88, in _run_code
  File "d:\02_Kotlin\my_kotlin_env\Lib\site-packages\run_kotlin_kernel\__main__.py", line 10, in <module>
02:39:52.315 [warn] StdErr from Kernel Process main(sys.argv)
  File "d:\02_Kotlin\my_kotlin_env\Lib\site-packages\run_kotlin_kernel\__main__.py", line 6, in main
02:39:52.315 [warn] StdErr from Kernel Process run_kernel(*args[1:])
  File "d:\02_Kotlin\my_kotlin_env\Lib\site-packages\run_kotlin_kernel\run_kernel.py", line 12, in run_kernel
02:39:52.315 [warn] StdErr from Kernel Process run_kernel_impl(*args)
  File "d:\02_Kotlin\my_kotlin_env\Lib\site-packages\run_kotlin_kernel\run_kernel.py", line 75, in run_kernel_impl
02:39:52.316 [warn] StdErr from Kernel Process subprocess.call([java] + jvm_args + ['-jar'] + debug_list + jar_args)
  File "D:\04_Phython_Core\Lib\subprocess.py", line 389, in call
02:39:52.316 [warn] StdErr from Kernel Process with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\04_Phython_Core\Lib\subprocess.py", line 1026, in __init__
02:39:52.317 [warn] StdErr from Kernel Process self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "D:\04_Phython_Core\Lib\subprocess.py", line 1538, in _execute_child
02:39:52.318 [warn] StdErr from Kernel Process hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
02:39:52.318 [warn] StdErr from Kernel Process ^^^^^^^^^^^^
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] Sistem belirtilen dosyayı bulamıyor
02:39:52.328 [error] Disposing kernel process due to an error Error: The kernel died. Error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 198, in _run_module_as_main
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 88, in _run_code
  File "d:\02_Kotlin\my_kotlin_env\Lib\site-packages\run_kotlin_kernel\__main__.py", line 10, in <module>
    main(sys.argv)
  File "d:\02_Kotlin\my_kotlin_env\Lib\site-packages\run_kotlin_kernel\__main__.py", line 6, in main
    run_kernel(*args[1:])
  File "d:\02_Kotlin\my_kotlin_env\Lib\site-packages\run_kotlin_kernel\run_kernel.py", line 12, in run_kernel
    run_kernel_impl(*args)
  File "d:\02_Kotlin\my_kotlin_env\Lib\site-packages\run_kotlin_kernel\run_kernel.py", line 75, in run_kernel_impl
    subprocess.call([java] + jvm_args + ['-jar'] + debug_list + jar_args)
  File "D:\04_Phython_Core\Lib\subprocess.py", line 389, in call
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\04_Phython_Core\Lib\subprocess.py", line 1026, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "D:\04_Phython_Core\Lib\subprocess.py", line 1538, in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] Sistem belirtilen dosyayı bulamıyor... View Jupyter [log](command:jupyter.viewOutput) for further details.
    > Kernel Id = .jvsc74a57bd02cf58050246a8fb90d5b6f26f72786d7604fc9ac535b400b803d90ad93e2fe03#kotlin.d:\02_Kotlin\my_kotlin_env\Scripts\python.exe.\.python#-m#run_kotlin_kernel#{connection_file}
    > Interpreter Id = d:\02_KOTLIN\MY_KOTLIN_ENV\SCRIPTS\PYTHON.EXE
    > at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (~\.vscode\extensions\ms-toolsai.jupyter-2023.8.1002501831-win32-x64\out\extension.node.js:24:86447)
    > stdErr = Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 198, in _run_module_as_main
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 88, in _run_code
  File "d:\02_Kotlin\my_kotlin_env\Lib\site-packages\run_kotlin_kernel\__main__.py", line 10, in <module>
    main(sys.argv)
  File "d:\02_Kotlin\my_kotlin_env\Lib\site-packages\run_kotlin_kernel\__main__.py", line 6, in main
    run_kernel(*args[1:])
  File "d:\02_Kotlin\my_kotlin_env\Lib\site-packages\run_kotlin_kernel\run_kernel.py", line 12, in run_kernel
    run_kernel_impl(*args)
  File "d:\02_Kotlin\my_kotlin_env\Lib\site-packages\run_kotlin_kernel\run_kernel.py", line 75, in run_kernel_impl
    subprocess.call([java] + jvm_args + ['-jar'] + debug_list + jar_args)
  File "D:\04_Phython_Core\Lib\subprocess.py", line 389, in call
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\04_Phython_Core\Lib\subprocess.py", line 1026, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "D:\04_Phython_Core\Lib\subprocess.py", line 1538, in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] Sistem belirtilen dosyayı bulamıyor
02:39:52.328 [info] Dispose Kernel process 28204.
02:39:52.329 [error] Kernel Launcher. launch, Class name = ty, completed in 2285ms, has a falsy return value, Arg 1: ".jvsc74a57bd02cf58050246a8fb90d5b6f26f72786d7604fc9ac535b400b803d90ad93e2fe03#kotlin.d:\\02_Kotlin\\my_kotlin_env\\Scripts\\python.exe.\\.python#-m#run_kotlin_kernel#{connection_file}", Arg 2: 60000, Arg 3: "/d:/02_Kotlin/notebook.ipynb", Arg 4: "d:\\02_Kotlin", Arg 5: "" Error: The kernel died. Error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 198, in _run_module_as_main
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 88, in _run_code
  File "d:\02_Kotlin\my_kotlin_env\Lib\site-packages\run_kotlin_kernel\__main__.py", line 10, in <module>
    main(sys.argv)
  File "d:\02_Kotlin\my_kotlin_env\Lib\site-packages\run_kotlin_kernel\__main__.py", line 6, in main
    run_kernel(*args[1:])
  File "d:\02_Kotlin\my_kotlin_env\Lib\site-packages\run_kotlin_kernel\run_kernel.py", line 12, in run_kernel
    run_kernel_impl(*args)
  File "d:\02_Kotlin\my_kotlin_env\Lib\site-packages\run_kotlin_kernel\run_kernel.py", line 75, in run_kernel_impl
    subprocess.call([java] + jvm_args + ['-jar'] + debug_list + jar_args)
  File "D:\04_Phython_Core\Lib\subprocess.py", line 389, in call
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\04_Phython_Core\Lib\subprocess.py", line 1026, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "D:\04_Phython_Core\Lib\subprocess.py", line 1538, in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] Sistem belirtilen dosyayı bulamıyor... View Jupyter [log](command:jupyter.viewOutput) for further details.
    > Kernel Id = .jvsc74a57bd02cf58050246a8fb90d5b6f26f72786d7604fc9ac535b400b803d90ad93e2fe03#kotlin.d:\02_Kotlin\my_kotlin_env\Scripts\python.exe.\.python#-m#run_kotlin_kernel#{connection_file}
    > Interpreter Id = d:\02_KOTLIN\MY_KOTLIN_ENV\SCRIPTS\PYTHON.EXE
    > at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (~\.vscode\extensions\ms-toolsai.jupyter-2023.8.1002501831-win32-x64\out\extension.node.js:24:86447)
    > stdErr = Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 198, in _run_module_as_main
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 88, in _run_code
  File "d:\02_Kotlin\my_kotlin_env\Lib\site-packages\run_kotlin_kernel\__main__.py", line 10, in <module>
    main(sys.argv)
  File "d:\02_Kotlin\my_kotlin_env\Lib\site-packages\run_kotlin_kernel\__main__.py", line 6, in main
    run_kernel(*args[1:])
  File "d:\02_Kotlin\my_kotlin_env\Lib\site-packages\run_kotlin_kernel\run_kernel.py", line 12, in run_kernel
    run_kernel_impl(*args)
  File "d:\02_Kotlin\my_kotlin_env\Lib\site-packages\run_kotlin_kernel\run_kernel.py", line 75, in run_kernel_impl
    subprocess.call([java] + jvm_args + ['-jar'] + debug_list + jar_args)
  File "D:\04_Phython_Core\Lib\subprocess.py", line 389, in call
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\04_Phython_Core\Lib\subprocess.py", line 1026, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "D:\04_Phython_Core\Lib\subprocess.py", line 1538, in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] Sistem belirtilen dosyayı bulamıyor
02:39:52.329 [error] Failed to connect raw kernel session: Error: The kernel died. Error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 198, in _run_module_as_main
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 88, in _run_code
  File "d:\02_Kotlin\my_kotlin_env\Lib\site-packages\run_kotlin_kernel\__main__.py", line 10, in <module>
    main(sys.argv)
  File "d:\02_Kotlin\my_kotlin_env\Lib\site-packages\run_kotlin_kernel\__main__.py", line 6, in main
    run_kernel(*args[1:])
  File "d:\02_Kotlin\my_kotlin_env\Lib\site-packages\run_kotlin_kernel\run_kernel.py", line 12, in run_kernel
    run_kernel_impl(*args)
  File "d:\02_Kotlin\my_kotlin_env\Lib\site-packages\run_kotlin_kernel\run_kernel.py", line 75, in run_kernel_impl
    subprocess.call([java] + jvm_args + ['-jar'] + debug_list + jar_args)
  File "D:\04_Phython_Core\Lib\subprocess.py", line 389, in call
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\04_Phython_Core\Lib\subprocess.py", line 1026, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "D:\04_Phython_Core\Lib\subprocess.py", line 1538, in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] Sistem belirtilen dosyayı bulamıyor... View Jupyter [log](command:jupyter.viewOutput) for further details.
02:39:52.330 [warn] Error occurred while trying to start the kernel, options.disableUI=false Error: The kernel died. Error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 198, in _run_module_as_main
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 88, in _run_code
  File "d:\02_Kotlin\my_kotlin_env\Lib\site-packages\run_kotlin_kernel\__main__.py", line 10, in <module>
    main(sys.argv)
  File "d:\02_Kotlin\my_kotlin_env\Lib\site-packages\run_kotlin_kernel\__main__.py", line 6, in main
    run_kernel(*args[1:])
  File "d:\02_Kotlin\my_kotlin_env\Lib\site-packages\run_kotlin_kernel\run_kernel.py", line 12, in run_kernel
    run_kernel_impl(*args)
  File "d:\02_Kotlin\my_kotlin_env\Lib\site-packages\run_kotlin_kernel\run_kernel.py", line 75, in run_kernel_impl
    subprocess.call([java] + jvm_args + ['-jar'] + debug_list + jar_args)
  File "D:\04_Phython_Core\Lib\subprocess.py", line 389, in call
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\04_Phython_Core\Lib\subprocess.py", line 1026, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "D:\04_Phython_Core\Lib\subprocess.py", line 1538, in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] Sistem belirtilen dosyayı bulamıyor... View Jupyter [log](command:jupyter.viewOutput) for further details.
    > Kernel Id = .jvsc74a57bd02cf58050246a8fb90d5b6f26f72786d7604fc9ac535b400b803d90ad93e2fe03#kotlin.d:\02_Kotlin\my_kotlin_env\Scripts\python.exe.\.python#-m#run_kotlin_kernel#{connection_file}
    > Interpreter Id = d:\02_KOTLIN\MY_KOTLIN_ENV\SCRIPTS\PYTHON.EXE
    > at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (~\.vscode\extensions\ms-toolsai.jupyter-2023.8.1002501831-win32-x64\out\extension.node.js:24:86447)
    > stdErr = Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 198, in _run_module_as_main
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 88, in _run_code
  File "d:\02_Kotlin\my_kotlin_env\Lib\site-packages\run_kotlin_kernel\__main__.py", line 10, in <module>
    main(sys.argv)
  File "d:\02_Kotlin\my_kotlin_env\Lib\site-packages\run_kotlin_kernel\__main__.py", line 6, in main
    run_kernel(*args[1:])
  File "d:\02_Kotlin\my_kotlin_env\Lib\site-packages\run_kotlin_kernel\run_kernel.py", line 12, in run_kernel
    run_kernel_impl(*args)
  File "d:\02_Kotlin\my_kotlin_env\Lib\site-packages\run_kotlin_kernel\run_kernel.py", line 75, in run_kernel_impl
    subprocess.call([java] + jvm_args + ['-jar'] + debug_list + jar_args)
  File "D:\04_Phython_Core\Lib\subprocess.py", line 389, in call
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\04_Phython_Core\Lib\subprocess.py", line 1026, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "D:\04_Phython_Core\Lib\subprocess.py", line 1538, in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] Sistem belirtilen dosyayı bulamıyor
02:39:52.330 [warn] Kernel Error, context = start Error: The kernel died. Error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 198, in _run_module_as_main
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 88, in _run_code
  File "d:\02_Kotlin\my_kotlin_env\Lib\site-packages\run_kotlin_kernel\__main__.py", line 10, in <module>
    main(sys.argv)
  File "d:\02_Kotlin\my_kotlin_env\Lib\site-packages\run_kotlin_kernel\__main__.py", line 6, in main
    run_kernel(*args[1:])
  File "d:\02_Kotlin\my_kotlin_env\Lib\site-packages\run_kotlin_kernel\run_kernel.py", line 12, in run_kernel
    run_kernel_impl(*args)
  File "d:\02_Kotlin\my_kotlin_env\Lib\site-packages\run_kotlin_kernel\run_kernel.py", line 75, in run_kernel_impl
    subprocess.call([java] + jvm_args + ['-jar'] + debug_list + jar_args)
  File "D:\04_Phython_Core\Lib\subprocess.py", line 389, in call
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\04_Phython_Core\Lib\subprocess.py", line 1026, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "D:\04_Phython_Core\Lib\subprocess.py", line 1538, in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] Sistem belirtilen dosyayı bulamıyor... View Jupyter [log](command:jupyter.viewOutput) for further details.
    > Kernel Id = .jvsc74a57bd02cf58050246a8fb90d5b6f26f72786d7604fc9ac535b400b803d90ad93e2fe03#kotlin.d:\02_Kotlin\my_kotlin_env\Scripts\python.exe.\.python#-m#run_kotlin_kernel#{connection_file}
    > Interpreter Id = d:\02_KOTLIN\MY_KOTLIN_ENV\SCRIPTS\PYTHON.EXE
    > at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (~\.vscode\extensions\ms-toolsai.jupyter-2023.8.1002501831-win32-x64\out\extension.node.js:24:86447)
    > stdErr = Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 198, in _run_module_as_main
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 88, in _run_code
  File "d:\02_Kotlin\my_kotlin_env\Lib\site-packages\run_kotlin_kernel\__main__.py", line 10, in <module>
    main(sys.argv)
  File "d:\02_Kotlin\my_kotlin_env\Lib\site-packages\run_kotlin_kernel\__main__.py", line 6, in main
    run_kernel(*args[1:])
  File "d:\02_Kotlin\my_kotlin_env\Lib\site-packages\run_kotlin_kernel\run_kernel.py", line 12, in run_kernel
    run_kernel_impl(*args)
  File "d:\02_Kotlin\my_kotlin_env\Lib\site-packages\run_kotlin_kernel\run_kernel.py", line 75, in run_kernel_impl
    subprocess.call([java] + jvm_args + ['-jar'] + debug_list + jar_args)
  File "D:\04_Phython_Core\Lib\subprocess.py", line 389, in call
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\04_Phython_Core\Lib\subprocess.py", line 1026, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "D:\04_Phython_Core\Lib\subprocess.py", line 1538, in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] Sistem belirtilen dosyayı bulamıyor
02:39:52.336 [info] Process Execution: d:\02_Kotlin\my_kotlin_env\Scripts\python.exe -c "import ipykernel;print('6af208d0-cb9c-427f-b937-ff563e17efdf')"
02:39:52.761 [info] Dispose Kernel 'd:\02_Kotlin\notebook.ipynb' associated with 'd:\02_Kotlin\notebook.ipynb'
02:39:52.762 [error] Error in execution Error: The kernel died. Error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 198, in _run_module_as_main
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 88, in _run_code
  File "d:\02_Kotlin\my_kotlin_env\Lib\site-packages\run_kotlin_kernel\__main__.py", line 10, in <module>
    main(sys.argv)
  File "d:\02_Kotlin\my_kotlin_env\Lib\site-packages\run_kotlin_kernel\__main__.py", line 6, in main
    run_kernel(*args[1:])
  File "d:\02_Kotlin\my_kotlin_env\Lib\site-packages\run_kotlin_kernel\run_kernel.py", line 12, in run_kernel
    run_kernel_impl(*args)
  File "d:\02_Kotlin\my_kotlin_env\Lib\site-packages\run_kotlin_kernel\run_kernel.py", line 75, in run_kernel_impl
    subprocess.call([java] + jvm_args + ['-jar'] + debug_list + jar_args)
  File "D:\04_Phython_Core\Lib\subprocess.py", line 389, in call
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\04_Phython_Core\Lib\subprocess.py", line 1026, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "D:\04_Phython_Core\Lib\subprocess.py", line 1538, in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] Sistem belirtilen dosyayı bulamıyor... View Jupyter [log](command:jupyter.viewOutput) for further details.
    > Kernel Id = .jvsc74a57bd02cf58050246a8fb90d5b6f26f72786d7604fc9ac535b400b803d90ad93e2fe03#kotlin.d:\02_Kotlin\my_kotlin_env\Scripts\python.exe.\.python#-m#run_kotlin_kernel#{connection_file}
    > Interpreter Id = d:\02_KOTLIN\MY_KOTLIN_ENV\SCRIPTS\PYTHON.EXE
    > at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (~\.vscode\extensions\ms-toolsai.jupyter-2023.8.1002501831-win32-x64\out\extension.node.js:24:86447)
    > stdErr = Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 198, in _run_module_as_main
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 88, in _run_code
  File "d:\02_Kotlin\my_kotlin_env\Lib\site-packages\run_kotlin_kernel\__main__.py", line 10, in <module>
    main(sys.argv)
  File "d:\02_Kotlin\my_kotlin_env\Lib\site-packages\run_kotlin_kernel\__main__.py", line 6, in main
    run_kernel(*args[1:])
  File "d:\02_Kotlin\my_kotlin_env\Lib\site-packages\run_kotlin_kernel\run_kernel.py", line 12, in run_kernel
    run_kernel_impl(*args)
  File "d:\02_Kotlin\my_kotlin_env\Lib\site-packages\run_kotlin_kernel\run_kernel.py", line 75, in run_kernel_impl
    subprocess.call([java] + jvm_args + ['-jar'] + debug_list + jar_args)
  File "D:\04_Phython_Core\Lib\subprocess.py", line 389, in call
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\04_Phython_Core\Lib\subprocess.py", line 1026, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "D:\04_Phython_Core\Lib\subprocess.py", line 1538, in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] Sistem belirtilen dosyayı bulamıyor
02:39:52.762 [error] Error in execution (get message for cell) Error: The kernel died. Error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 198, in _run_module_as_main
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 88, in _run_code
  File "d:\02_Kotlin\my_kotlin_env\Lib\site-packages\run_kotlin_kernel\__main__.py", line 10, in <module>
    main(sys.argv)
  File "d:\02_Kotlin\my_kotlin_env\Lib\site-packages\run_kotlin_kernel\__main__.py", line 6, in main
    run_kernel(*args[1:])
  File "d:\02_Kotlin\my_kotlin_env\Lib\site-packages\run_kotlin_kernel\run_kernel.py", line 12, in run_kernel
    run_kernel_impl(*args)
  File "d:\02_Kotlin\my_kotlin_env\Lib\site-packages\run_kotlin_kernel\run_kernel.py", line 75, in run_kernel_impl
    subprocess.call([java] + jvm_args + ['-jar'] + debug_list + jar_args)
  File "D:\04_Phython_Core\Lib\subprocess.py", line 389, in call
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\04_Phython_Core\Lib\subprocess.py", line 1026, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "D:\04_Phython_Core\Lib\subprocess.py", line 1538, in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] Sistem belirtilen dosyayı bulamıyor... View Jupyter [log](command:jupyter.viewOutput) for further details.
    > Kernel Id = .jvsc74a57bd02cf58050246a8fb90d5b6f26f72786d7604fc9ac535b400b803d90ad93e2fe03#kotlin.d:\02_Kotlin\my_kotlin_env\Scripts\python.exe.\.python#-m#run_kotlin_kernel#{connection_file}
    > Interpreter Id = d:\02_KOTLIN\MY_KOTLIN_ENV\SCRIPTS\PYTHON.EXE
    > at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (~\.vscode\extensions\ms-toolsai.jupyter-2023.8.1002501831-win32-x64\out\extension.node.js:24:86447)
    > stdErr = Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 198, in _run_module_as_main
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 88, in _run_code
  File "d:\02_Kotlin\my_kotlin_env\Lib\site-packages\run_kotlin_kernel\__main__.py", line 10, in <module>
    main(sys.argv)
  File "d:\02_Kotlin\my_kotlin_env\Lib\site-packages\run_kotlin_kernel\__main__.py", line 6, in main
    run_kernel(*args[1:])
  File "d:\02_Kotlin\my_kotlin_env\Lib\site-packages\run_kotlin_kernel\run_kernel.py", line 12, in run_kernel
    run_kernel_impl(*args)
  File "d:\02_Kotlin\my_kotlin_env\Lib\site-packages\run_kotlin_kernel\run_kernel.py", line 75, in run_kernel_impl
    subprocess. Call([java] + jvm_args + ['-jar'] + debug_list + jar_args)
  File "D:\04_Phython_Core\Lib\subprocess.py", line 389, in call
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\04_Phython_Core\Lib\subprocess.py", line 1026, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "D:\04_Phython_Core\Lib\subprocess.py", line 1538, in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] Sistem belirtilen dosyayı bulamıyor
02:39:52.769 [info] Process Execution: d:\02_Kotlin\my_kotlin_env\Scripts\python.exe -c "import ipykernel;print('6af208d0-cb9c-427f-b937-ff563e17efdf')"
02:39:53.221 [info] End cell 0 execution @ undefined, started @ undefined, elapsed time = 0s
```

How can do this properly ? I can send more details if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should configure enviroment variable `JAVA_HOME` and add `%JAVA_HOME%\bin` into `PATH`.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Dear derker, I configured Java Home as; "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath" and added %JAVA_HOME%\bin to path but no change. I get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, log would be appreciated. It's not clear what exact file can't be found.

There could be problems with Kotlin kernel installation because of python's multiple environments. Specificially for this you can [try to run this](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlin-jupyter#troubleshooting):

```
python -m kotlin_kernel fix-kernelspec-location
```

Comment: Dear Ilya; I have updated the question with the details you have requested. I also tried above command but no luck.

Comment: @BlueHawk77 what is the contents of `C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath`? Please, add printing of the arguments list in `d:\02_Kotlin\my_kotlin_env\Lib\site-packages\run_kotlin_kernel\run_kernel.py` right before subprocess call.

Comment: Dear Ilya contents of C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath is 3 files java.exe, javaw.exe and javaws.exe.
ı didn't get what you meant by "adding printing of the arguments list in d:\02_Kotlin\my_kotlin_env\Lib\site-packages\run_kotlin_kernel\run_kernel.py right before subprocess call."

Comment: Also now my question has evolved to this;

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77246153/using-kotlin-kernel-on-jupyter-notebook