# Using Kotlin Kernel on Jupyter Notebook

Tags: kotlin, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to use Kotlin Kernel on Jupyter notebook (on VScode).

I have created a virtual environment.

I have installed jupyter notebook and kotlin-jupyter-kernel via pip.

java -version

```
openjdk version "17.0.8.1" 2023-08-24
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Temurin-17.0.8.1+1 (build 17.0.8.1+1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Temurin-17.0.8.1+1 (build 17.0.8.1+1, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Java seems to be installed properly. ( I can also see path at system environments )

kotlinc -version

```
info: kotlinc-jvm 1.9.0 (JRE 17.0.8.1+1)
```

kotlin seems to be installed properly.  ( I can also see path at system environments )

When I select kernel from jupyter notebook and run a code, it says;

```
Failed to start the Kernel. 
214  [main] INFO  ikotlin - Kernel args: -classpath=d:\01_SoftDev\05_Kotlin\kotlin_env\Lib\site-packages\run_kotlin_kernel\jars\lib-0.11.0-385.jar;d:\01_SoftDev\05_Kotlin\kotlin_env\Lib\site-packages\run_kotlin_kernel\jars\api-0.11.0-385.jar;d:\01_SoftDev\05_Kotlin\kotlin_env\Lib\site-packages\run_kotlin_kernel\jars\kotlin-script-runtime-1.8.20.jar;d:\01_SoftDev\05_Kotlin\kotlin_env\Lib\site-packages\run_kotlin_kernel\jars\kotlin-reflect-1.8.20.jar;d:\01_SoftDev\05_Kotlin\kotlin_env\Lib\site-packages\run_kotlin_kernel\jars\kotlin-stdlib-1.8.20.jar;d:\01_SoftDev\05_Kotlin\kotlin_env\Lib\site-packages\run_kotlin_kernel\jars\kotlin-stdlib-common-1.8.20.jar;d:\01_SoftDev\05_Kotlin\kotlin_env\Lib\site-packages\run_kotlin_kernel\jars\annotations-13.0.jar;d:\01_SoftDev\05_Kotlin\kotlin_env\Lib\site-packages\run_kotlin_kernel\jars\kotlinx-serialization-json-jvm-1.4.1.jar;d:\01_SoftDev\05_Kotlin\kotlin_env\Lib\site-packages\run_kotlin_kernel\jars\kotlinx-serialization-core-jvm-1.4.1.jar;d:\01_SoftDev\05_Kotlin\kotlin_env\Lib\site-packages\run_kotlin_kernel\jars\kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.20.jar;d:\01_SoftDev\05_Kotlin\kotlin_env\Lib\site-packages\run_kotlin_kernel\jars\kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.20.jar, c:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Roaming\jupyter\runtime\kernel-v2-6860Q1wZ01qlUfH1.json, -home=d:\01_SoftDev\05_Kotlin\kotlin_env\Lib\site-packages\run_kotlin_kernel, -debugPort=1044 
536  [main] ERROR ikotlin - exception running kernel with args: "-classpath=d:\01_SoftDev\05_Kotlin\kotlin_env\Lib\site-packages\run_kotlin_kernel\jars\lib-0.11.0-385.jar;d:\01_SoftDev\05_Kotlin\kotlin_env\Lib\site-packages\run_kotlin_kernel\jars\api-0.11.0-385.jar;d:\01_SoftDev\05_Kotlin\kotlin_env\Lib\site-packages\run_kotlin_kernel\jars\kotlin-script-runtime-1.8.20.jar;d:\01_SoftDev\05_Kotlin\kotlin_env\Lib\site-packages\run_kotlin_kernel\jars\kotlin-reflect-1.8.20.jar;d:\01_SoftDev\05_Kotlin\kotlin_env\Lib\site-packages\run_kotlin_kernel\jars\kotlin-stdlib-1.8.20.jar;d:\01_SoftDev\05_Kotlin\kotlin_env\Lib\site-packages\run_kotlin_kernel\jars\kotlin-stdlib-common-1.8.20.jar;d:\01_SoftDev\05_Kotlin\kotlin_env\Lib\site-packages\run_kotlin_kernel\jars\annotations-13.0.jar;d:\01_SoftDev\05_Kotlin\kotlin_env\Lib\site-packages\run_kotlin_kernel\jars\kotlinx-serialization-json-jvm-1.4.1.jar;d:\01_SoftDev\05_Kotlin\kotlin_env\Lib\site-packages\run_kotlin_kernel\jars\kotlinx-serialization-core-jvm-1.4.1.jar;d:\01_SoftDev\05_Kotlin\kotlin_env\Lib\site-packages\run_kotlin_kernel\jars\kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.20.jar;d:\01_SoftDev\05_Kotlin\kotlin_env\Lib\site-packages\run_kotlin_kernel\jars\kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.20.jar, c:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Roaming\jupyter\runtime\kernel-v2-6860Q1wZ01qlUfH1.json, -home=d:\01_SoftDev\05_Kotlin\kotlin_env\Lib\site-packages\run_kotlin_kernel, -debugPort=1044" 
java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot find std�n_port in config
    at org.jetbrains.kotlinx.jupyter.startup.KernelJupyterParamsSerializer$deserialize$1.invoke(arguments.kt:90)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlinx.jupyter.startup.KernelJupyterParamsSerializer$deserialize$1.invoke(arguments.kt:88)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlinx.jupyter.startup.ArgumentsKt.createKernelPorts(arguments.kt:28)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlinx.jupyter.startup.KernelJupyterParamsSerializer.deserialize(arguments.kt:88)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlinx.jupyter.startup.KernelJupyterParamsSerializer.deserialize(arguments.kt:76)
    at kotlinx.serialization.json.internal.StreamingJsonDecoder.decodeSerializableValue(StreamingJsonDecoder.kt:70)
    at kotlinx.serialization.json.Json.decodeFromString(Json.kt:97)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlinx.jupyter.startup.KernelJupyterParams$Companion.fromFile(arguments.kt:205)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlinx.jupyter.startup.KernelArgs.parseParams(arguments.kt:43)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlinx.jupyter.startup.ArgumentsKt.getConfig(arguments.kt:190)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlinx.jupyter.IkotlinKt.main(ikotlin.kt:77). 
View Jupyter log for further details.
```

How can I solve it ?

Thanks in advance for assistance.

Comment: Not sure about VSCode, but Jetbrains supports [Kotlin Notebooks in Intellij Ultimate](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/16340-kotlin-notebook), which I figure most Kotlin developers are using instead of VSCode anyway.